# Action-reaction

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

Suppose I have connected a string with a block and I'm holding another end of string and pulling with a constant force, say $F$. Now if I'm pulling this string by constant force $F$, this string is also pulling me
with same force but in opposite direction.

Now string is pulling me in opposite direction to what I'm making the string move, therefore I should also move in that direction in which string is pulling me but I'm making string move in opposite direction. Therefore, there must also be some force which is pulling me in the direction along which I'm making string move. what is that force?

Similarly string is pulling block towards the direction along which it is moving but block is also pulling string towards the direction opposite to which string is moving then why is string moving in that direction, there must be some force on string which is balancing force exerted by block on string, what is that force?

Comment: THE question: do you believe Newton's 3rd law is true?

Comment: Don't forget you have feet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let’s consider the string. There are two horizontal forces acting on the string - the force with which you are pulling the string, and the force exerted by the block on the string. If the string has some (small) mass and it is accelerating then there must be a non-zero net force on the string. So the force with which you are pulling the string must be greater than the force exerted by the block on the string.

However, we usually make one (or both) of two assumptions, which simplify the situation. Either we assume the string is moving at a constant velocity. Or we assume the string has a mass that is so small we can call it zero - we say the string is “light”. In either case the net force on the string is zero, and so the force with which you are pulling the string and the force exerted by the block on the string are equal in magnitude (and are also equal to the force exerted by the string on the block).

Now consider the forces on you. You are pulling the string horizontally so the string exerts an equal and opposite horizontal force on you. If you are standing still on the ground then the net horizontal force on you must be zero. So there must be another horizontal force acting on you. That force is the *friction* between you and the ground.

Of course, there is also friction between the block and the ground. If this is greater than the friction between you and the ground (because the block is very heavy, or it is nailed to the ground, or it is on a rough surface and you are standing on ice, or you jump in the air as you are pulling) then you will find you cannot move the block. If you pull harder than the friction between you and the ground (or if you jump in the air) then you will pull yourself towards the block instead.

So a “tug of war” between two teams is not really decided by which team can pull the hardest, since the harder you pull, the harder the rope pulls back on you. It is about which team has the greatest friction - this is why heavier teams have an advantage.

Answer (score 0):

The action and reaction are exerted on the different bodies and different bodies can have different masses. If we just assume two objects A and B and the forces involved are $\pm F$ then the accelerations are $a_A=F/m_A$, and $a_B=-F/m_B$. If $m_B/m_A\ll 1$, then we would normally say the object B moves towards object A because the acceleration of B is more perceivable than that of A, but really both are moving towards each other. We would normally also neglect the mass of the string but if you want you can include it into object B.